# Is there a way to avoid creating "status: incomplete" subscriptions during Stripe Checkout?

Tags: stripe-payments

###### Background:

When creating subscriptions through the Stripe API, you can use `payment_behavior: error_if_incomplete` when you want Stripe to return an HTTP 402 status code in case a subscription’s first invoice cannot be paid. In this case Stripe does not create a subscription at all if the payment fails.

###### Question:

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior when using Stripe Checkout?

My experience is that even if the payment fails, Stripe creates a subscription with `status: incomplete` which is then expired if no successful payment is made within 23 hours. I've checked the parameters for creating Checkout Sessions but found no option to set `payment_behavior` there.

###### Sources:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-payment_behavior
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bad News

Unfortunately this is not something that can be configured presently.  When Checkout creates a subscription, all the parameters not provided directly are set to the Subscription default.  The default [`payment_behavior`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-payment_behavior) for a Subscription is `default_incomplete`.

### Good News

You *can* achieve this behavior using [Webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks). You would listen for the [`invoice.payment_failed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.payment_failed) event, check the [`billing_reason`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason) property of the invoice is `subscription_create` (identifies the first invoice of a new subscription), and then [cancel](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel) the [related subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-subscription).

If you are using Subscriptions and Invoices, it is [recommended](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#understand) you use webhooks anyway to keep track of changes in status.

Comment: Unfortunately canceling the subscription based on `invoice.payment_failed` appears to also cancel the checkout session, so a user's session would immediately expire if their payment fails. Do you know if there is a workaround for that?

Comment: Is the user still on-session (interacting with the UI)?  In that case it wouldn't make sense to cancel the subscription, just ask for a different payment method.  If you just want to redirect them back to the Checkout UI then likely the best approach is to create a new Checkout Session.  You can retrieve the Line Items from the past one and use them to create the new session so it's mostly identical.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items

Comment: Alternatively you can create the checkout sessions with `after_expiration.recovery.enabled=true`.  This will generate a Recovery URL on the Checkout object that you can redirect your users to.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-after_expiration-recovery-enabled